# Differences between GeoLite2-City and GeoLiteCityv6 (Legacy)

Tags: geoip

We have been using GeoLiteCityv6 for our product and migrated to GeoLite2-City.
Unfortunately we see huge differences when resolving the same IP addresses with both databases. GeoLite2-City provides less details, especially for regions.

E.g. when resolving the IP address 2.139.175.146 we get *Country=Spain, Region=Catalonia, City=Barcelona* with GeoLiteCityv6 but only *Country=Spain, Region=-, City=Barcelona* with GeoLite2-City. We checked several IP addresses for Spain and did not get even one region information.
I'm afraid this is true for many other countries too.

Has anybody experienced similar problems?
Is there statement from maxmind about any blurs in the free version?

Thx for any comment!
bruno

Answer (score 0):

GeoLite2 does have subdivision information for that IP address. Here is the full record:

```
{
  "city": 
    {
      "geoname_id": 
        3128760 <uint32>
      "names": 
        {
          "de": 
            "Barcelona" <utf8_string>
          "en": 
            "Barcelona" <utf8_string>
          "es": 
            "Barcelona" <utf8_string>
          "fr": 
            "Barcelone" <utf8_string>
          "ja": 
            "バルセロナ" <utf8_string>
          "pt-BR": 
            "Barcelona" <utf8_string>
          "ru": 
            "Барселона" <utf8_string>
          "zh-CN": 
            "巴塞罗那" <utf8_string>
        }
    }
  "continent": 
    {
      "code": 
        "EU" <utf8_string>
      "geoname_id": 
        6255148 <uint32>
      "names": 
        {
          "de": 
            "Europa" <utf8_string>
          "en": 
            "Europe" <utf8_string>
          "es": 
            "Europa" <utf8_string>
          "fr": 
            "Europe" <utf8_string>
          "ja": 
            "ヨーロッパ" <utf8_string>
          "pt-BR": 
            "Europa" <utf8_string>
          "ru": 
            "Европа" <utf8_string>
          "zh-CN": 
            "欧洲" <utf8_string>
        }
    }
  "country": 
    {
      "geoname_id": 
        2510769 <uint32>
      "iso_code": 
        "ES" <utf8_string>
      "names": 
        {
          "de": 
            "Spanien" <utf8_string>
          "en": 
            "Spain" <utf8_string>
          "es": 
            "España" <utf8_string>
          "fr": 
            "Espagne" <utf8_string>
          "ja": 
            "スペイン" <utf8_string>
          "pt-BR": 
            "Espanha" <utf8_string>
          "ru": 
            "Испания" <utf8_string>
          "zh-CN": 
            "西班牙" <utf8_string>
        }
    }
  "location": 
    {
      "latitude": 
        41.388800 <double>
      "longitude": 
        2.159000 <double>
      "time_zone": 
        "Europe/Madrid" <utf8_string>
    }
  "postal": 
    {
      "code": 
        "08001" <utf8_string>
    }
  "registered_country": 
    {
      "geoname_id": 
        2510769 <uint32>
      "iso_code": 
        "ES" <utf8_string>
      "names": 
        {
          "de": 
            "Spanien" <utf8_string>
          "en": 
            "Spain" <utf8_string>
          "es": 
            "España" <utf8_string>
          "fr": 
            "Espagne" <utf8_string>
          "ja": 
            "スペイン" <utf8_string>
          "pt-BR": 
            "Espanha" <utf8_string>
          "ru": 
            "Испания" <utf8_string>
          "zh-CN": 
            "西班牙" <utf8_string>
        }
    }
  "subdivisions": 
    [
      {
        "geoname_id": 
          3336901 <uint32>
        "iso_code": 
          "CT" <utf8_string>
        "names": 
          {
            "de": 
              "Katalonien" <utf8_string>
            "en": 
              "Catalonia" <utf8_string>
            "es": 
              "Cataluña" <utf8_string>
            "fr": 
              "Catalogne" <utf8_string>
            "ja": 
              "カタロニア" <utf8_string>
            "pt-BR": 
              "Catalunha" <utf8_string>
            "ru": 
              "Каталония" <utf8_string>
          }
      }
      {
        "geoname_id": 
          3128759 <uint32>
        "iso_code": 
          "B" <utf8_string>
        "names": 
          {
            "de": 
              "Provinz Barcelona" <utf8_string>
            "en": 
              "Barcelona" <utf8_string>
            "es": 
              "Barcelona" <utf8_string>
            "fr": 
              "Province de Barcelone" <utf8_string>
            "ja": 
              "ばるせろな" <utf8_string>
          }
      }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the subdivision is "Catalonia" with a secondary subdivision of "Barcelona". Perhaps there is an error in the code doing that lookup.